# NHibernate messages going to the console no matter what

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, log4net

I have a console app using Fluent NHibernate.  I have configured it to log to various places using log4net. And it works great.  I can see the SQL that I want to see and can sent log output to various appenders.  The problem is that  I cannot suppress the log4net sql output going to the console.

The extra console output is not being controlled by my log4net config settings.  It always appears, no matter if I turn off all appenders.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have this property set to **true** in your nhibernate section in your app.config?

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
```

If so set it to false.

#### Edit

Here is a sample piece of code from the nhibernate source:

```
log.Debug(logMessage);
if (LogToStdout)
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine("NHibernate: " + statement);
}
```

In the above code `LogToStdout` is directly linked to the `show_sql` configuration property.  If you have this set to true nothing will stop it from writing to the console.  In regards to your comment you cannot control this via log4net.  You can only control what you are doing with the `log.Debug(logMessage)` via log4net.

Comment: Using fluent, but yes, that is set in the configuration.  Otherwise I would not see the messages at all.

Comment: Well this configuration will also send output to the console window I believe.

Comment: Yes, but in log4net I should be able to suppress and manage console output.

Comment: @DanielWilliams take a look at my edit above and you'll see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1):

To disable any logs put the following code:

```
< add key="nhibernate-logger" value="" />
```

into your appSettings section.

Answer (score 0):

The NHibernate logs don't help me much, I'll turn them on when I need them... I add these settings to the log4net section of my app.config:

```
    <logger name="NHibernate">
      <level value="OFF" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="NHibernate.SQL">
      <level value="OFF" />
    </logger>
```